# Google Play license check doCheck() method causes nullPointerException and force closes

Tags: java, android

The code below ends in a nullPointerException when run.

The logcat is first, the code is second.

Logcat:

```
     07-27 09:58:13.705: D/AndroidRuntime(18164): Shutting down VM
    0

        7-27 09:58:13

.705: W/dalvikvm(18164): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3c1f8)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liamwli.smsbusy/com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity.doCheck(Sms_busyActivity.java:142)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity.onCreate(Sms_busyActivity.java:60)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    07-27 09:58:13.710: E/AndroidRuntime(18164):    ... 11 more
    07-27 09:58:14.035: I/dalvikvm(18164): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-27 09:58:14.055: I/dalvikvm(18164): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    07-27 09:58:14.260: I/dalvikvm(18164): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-27 09:58:14.275: I/dalvikvm(18164): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    07-27 10:01:17.450: D/AndroidRuntime(18326): Shutting down VM
    07-27 10:01:17.455: W/dalvikvm(18326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3c1f8)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liamwli.smsbusy/com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity.doCheck(Sms_busyActivity.java:142)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity.onCreate(Sms_busyActivity.java:60)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    07-27 10:01:17.455: E/AndroidRuntime(18326):    ... 11 more
    07-27 10:01:17.855: I/dalvikvm(18326): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-27 10:01:17.860: I/dalvikvm(18326): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    07-27 10:01:17.990: I/dalvikvm(18326): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-27 10:01:17.995: I/dalvikvm(18326): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    07-27 10:04:32.645: D/AndroidRuntime(18561): Shutting down VM
    07-27 10:04:32.645: W/dalvikvm(18561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3c1f8)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liamwli.smsbusy/com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity.doCheck(Sms_busyActivity.java:140)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at com.liamwli.smsbusy.Sms_busyActivity.onCreate(Sms_busyActivity.java:58)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    07-27 10:04:32.645: E/AndroidRuntime(18561):    ... 11 more
    07-27 10:04:33.060: I/dalvikvm(18561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-27 10:04:33.065: I/dalvikvm(18561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    07-27 10:04:33.185: I/dalvikvm(18561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-27 10:04:33.215: I/dalvikvm(18561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    07-27 10:04:36.915: I/Process(18561): Sending signal. PID: 18561 SIG: 9
```

Line 140 is the mChecker.checkAccess line new line under the last bracket:

```
private void doCheck() {
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }
```

Line 58 is the call to the doCheck method:

```
doCheck();
```

The rest of the class is below:

```
package com.liamwli.smsbusy;

import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.Policy;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.StrictPolicy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Sms_busyActivity extends Activity {
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    ToggleButton endis;
    EditText message;
    Button smessage;
    SharedPreferences getPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String android_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext()
                .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        // if (!android_id.contentEquals("56d330123953677d")) {
        // Log.e("SMS Busy App", "Device ID not allowed. Exiting.");
        // finish();
        // } else {

        // Log.d("SMS Busy App", "Device ID Allowed");
        // }

        // Intent i = new Intent("com.liamwli.smsbusy.PREFS");
        // startActivity(i);
        setContentView(R.layout.def);

        doCheck();

        String KEY = "abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvqxyz"; //made up to post online

        endis = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.enableddis);

        smessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savemess);

        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

        getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        editor = getPrefs.edit();

        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

        final byte[] SALT = new byte[] { -46, 65, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64,
                51, 88, -95, -45, 77, -117, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64, 89 };

        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new StrictPolicy(), KEY);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        // ---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        Boolean state = getPrefs.getBoolean("enabled", false);

        // String stext = getPrefs.getString("text", "");

        // message.setText(stext);
        message.setText(getPrefs.getString("text", ""));

        if (message.getText().toString().contentEquals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to get saved message. Please resave.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        endis.setChecked(state);

        endis.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onCheckedChanged Called");

                // Toast.makeText(Sms_busyActivity.this, "App state changed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                editor = getPrefs.edit();
                if (endis.isChecked()) {
                    editor.putBoolean("enabled", true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("enabled", false);
                }
                editor.putString("text", message.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();

            }
        });

        smessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                editor = getPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("text", message.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                Log.d("smessage", "Message saved & commited");
                Toast.makeText(Sms_busyActivity.this, "Message Saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    private void doCheck() {
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 5
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onKeyDown Called");
            onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    // public void onBackPressed() {
    // Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onBackPressed Called");
    // finish();

    // }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onCreateOptionsMenu Called");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mmenu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.aboutme:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AboutMe.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void displayResult(final String result) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Button mCheckLicenseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                mCheckLicenseButton.setText("App Licenced. Click to continue.");
                mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(true);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            }
        });
    }

    class MyLicenseCheckerCallback extends Activity implements
            LicenseCheckerCallback {
        public void allow(int reason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // Should allow user access.
            displayResult(getString(R.string.allow));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void dontAllow(int reason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Sms_busyActivity.this)
                    .create();
            if (reason == Policy.RETRY) {
                // If the reason received from the policy is RETRY, it was
                // probably
                // due to a loss of connection with the service, so we should
                // give the
                // user a chance to retry. So show a dialog to retry.
                alert.setTitle("Please retry license check");
                alert.setMessage("The connection to the licensing server was lost. Please click retry below");
                alert.setButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, the user is not licensed to use this app.
                // Your response should always inform the user that the
                // application
                // is not licensed, but your behavior at that point can vary.
                // You might
                // provide the user a limited access version of your app or you
                // can
                // take them to Google Play to purchase the app.f
                setContentView(R.layout.def);
                alert.setTitle("Not Licensed");
                alert.setMessage("This app is not licensed. Please buy it off google play.");
                alert.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }




}
```

EDIT: Line numbers were off. New logcat generated. Please look again.

Comment: Which is line number 60 ? Sms_busyActivity.onCreateSms_busyActivity.java:60

Comment: In `onCreate()` you call `doCheck()` before initializing `mChecker`. This will very likely lead to a `NullPointerException` (same goes for `mLicenseCheckerCallback`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialise you mChecker after using it :

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new StrictPolicy(), KEY);

mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

doCheck();

String KEY = "abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvqxyz"; //made up to post online

endis = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.enableddis);

smessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savemess);

message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

getPrefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

editor = getPrefs.edit();

final byte[] SALT = new byte[] { -46, 65, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64,
        51, 88, -95, -45, 77, -117, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64, 89 };
```

Comment: This is still missing mLicenseCheckerCallback

Answer (score 0):

put below line before you call `doCheck()` method

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new StrictPolicy(), KEY);
```

accoding to your `onCreate()`, it should look like

```
    setContentView(R.layout.def);
    String KEY = "abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvqxyz"; //Because u are using key in next line hence move Key before next line
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new StrictPolicy(), KEY);// <<<THIS LINE SHOULD COME BEFORE doCheck CALLED

    doCheck();
```

and `setContentView(R.layout.def);` should be moved just after super call in oncreate.